# Displaying parsed JSON in UITableView

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

i have this UITableView in which i have parsed data from a webservice and loaded into the NSDictionary its all working fine the data shows id and imageurl into the tableview the problemn is the logo-id which is a int shows perfectly when i scroll down the tableview but when i scroll up the tableview it vanishes and when i csroll down it appear again and stays there

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Where we configure the cell in each row

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //    }
    // Configure the cell... setting the text of our cell's label

    NSDictionary *dic = [json objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


    NSString *strImage = [dic objectForKey:@"image-name-small"];
    NSURL *ImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[strImage stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    AsyncImageView *asyncImgView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 10, 100, 100)];
    asyncImgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    asyncImgView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor];
    [asyncImgView loadImageFromURL:ImageURL];





    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 25)];
    lbl.text = [dic objectForKey:@"logo-id"];
    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:asyncImgView];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Problem can be the use of addSubview like this. Check with `cell.textLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"logo-id"];`

Comment: just reuse the cells just remove comment line if(cell ==nil) { create and allocate cell}

Comment: @MidhunMP you were right it was the addsubview issue also please explain the reason ..sugan.s if i dont comment those lines it shows duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

If cell addSubview does not work try this:

```
[cell.contentView addSubView:lbl];
```

or try the default cell property:

```
cell.textLabel.text=@"sample text";
```

//Try this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
}
else
{
    for (UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews)
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
}

NSDictionary *dic = [json objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


NSString *strImage = [dic objectForKey:@"image-name-small"];
NSURL *ImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[strImage stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
AsyncImageView *asyncImgView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 10, 100, 100)];
asyncImgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
asyncImgView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor];
[asyncImgView loadImageFromURL:ImageURL];

UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 25)];
lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
lbl.text = [dic objectForKey:@"logo-id"];

[cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
[cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImgView];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: nope not working @satheeshwaran the default is only working but i want to position the text

Comment: its working now good code but stil its missing one id after a number of id

Comment: Sorry I did not get you, what is missing?? Can you share some screen shot.

Comment: the tableview list a one logo-id and image in each row there are 450 entries after a 15or20 rows one row doesnt show the record of logi-id

Comment: Does this problem come while using cell.textLabel.text?

Comment: see my edit now change label's bg color and see whether you see a empty label.

Comment: So UILabel is the culprit here. Ok can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath methods code here.

Comment: Did you replace cell addSubview with cell.contentView addSubview?

Comment: @user1440164 Did u try it?